# as3 animation with multiple images

Tags: actionscript-3, animation, flashdevelop

I have only 3 images that I'm working with for animating a running animal:
1: animal standing
2: animal in stride/jumping
3: animal on its back dead

Currently, I'm embedding them into the main class as sprites and changing their .alpha properties whenever I want one and not the other 2. Is there a better way to do what I'm doing? One of the annoying things is updating the properties for each sprite individually. It would be ideal to have one object and being able to change the image on the object so I would only have to change one object's properties.

Comment: I think the technique you are looking for is called [blitting](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/articles/actionscript_blitting.html)

Comment: Changing alpha is the worst approach, because changing alpha is costy. Also when you change alpha Flash Player still renders that object, even though it's not visible to user. Visibility change is a better approach, even better is to add and remove your `MovieClips` from stage as needed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For this it would be best to handle your animation in its own Class!
Something like this, let's say your animal is a horse so that's what I'll call the class

```
package  {

    import flash.display.Sprite;

    public class Horse extends Sprite{

        private var holder:Sprite = new Sprite();

        public function Horse() {

            var img1:Image1 = new Image1();// ur images from library
            var img2:Image2 = new Image2();
            var img3:Image2 = new Image3();

            holder.addChild(img1);
            holder.addChild(img2);
            holder.addChild(img3);

            addChild(holder);
            setImage(0);// set 1st image visible

        }   

        public function setImage(nr:uint):void
        {
            for(var i:int = 0; i < holder.length;i++;)
                holder[i].visible = false;

            holder[nr].visible = true;
        }
    }

}
```

then you would use it like this for example!

```
var horse:Horse = new Horse();
addChild(horse);
horse.x = 25; 
horse.y = 25; // move the whole object(all 3 images)
horse.setImage(2);// or to whatever frame you need
```

Use the visible attribute instead of the alpha value. If u just set alpha to 0 it will still be rendered and cost cpu. if you set visible to false it will not be rendered!

EDIT:
 As Amy pointed out, blitting is a possibilty here to, although the fastest aproach would be BitmapData Frame Assignment!
Here you keep all your Frames as BitmapData in a Vector, which you load from a SpriteSheet and just assign the new BitmapData to your Bitmap instead of using copyPixels. It's faster then blitting and you still have all your builtin methods availible!!

Comment: +1 This is what I was getting at, however Amy's comment pointing to 'blitting' was more of what I had in mind... utilizing a sprite sheet (single image loaded into a single object). I just didn't know how to explain it any further than what I did in my question as I didn't even know what sprite sheet was.

Comment: ok .. nP. FYI i made some tests recently. Where a display list animation (like my example) was as fast as Blitting. But FrameAssigment (BitmapData Assigned) was the fastet and easiest on cpu!

Comment: Updated Answer. Btw " (single image loaded into a single object) " is not quite right, with blitting you constantly copy portions from your spriteSheet

Comment: So you would attest that instead of loading a single sprite sheet and redrawing them into the bitmap object, embedding each image individually and then loading them into its own class and rendering them via their visible property would be less resource consumption? (CPU, memory, total output size). And this would still be true if (let's say) I have 40+ images? I could imagine importing 40 images is a headache to look at however :)

Comment: No you would still use a spriteSheet. At App init you fill a vector with the BitmapData's from a SpriteSheet and use those instead of using copyPixls on every tick.
My tests were with 100+ images

Comment: Oi I don't know how to 'fill a vector' with the 'BitmapData from a spritesheet' O.o .

Comment: Found some tutorials =D. I like this method a lot. Thank you for your help